# Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.7.3'] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I downloaded a new Spring Boot project from http://start.spring.io and I get an error. Please help me figure it out.

My `build.gradle`

```java
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.13.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.murprog'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '18'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

error

```java
Build file 'D:\java\myblog_grd\build.gradle' line: 2

Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.7.3'] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.7.3'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.7.3')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

Comment: What are your actions? Show me content of file `build.gradle` . Try run command with parameter `--info` and/or `--debug` and/or `--scan` . Try use system's terminal, not built-in terminal inside IDE. Tell me the result.

Comment: can I send pictures and the project itself from some social network.

Comment: You can edit the question, paste from Windows/macOS clipboard directly. It is the simplest and most efficient way.

Comment: I pasted build.gradle

Comment: Your `build.gradle` is nothing wrong. I checked by comparing with new `build.gradle` . 1) What is your Gradle version? 2) You use Gradle standalone or built-in Gradle inside IDE? 3) What is your IDE? 4) What is your JDK version?

Comment: java version "18.0.2.1" 2022-08-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2.1+1-1)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2.1+1-1, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip

Comment: I am using built in gradle on intellij idea

Comment: @DoNhuVy  ??????

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to build a project with Java 11 and spring boot plugin 2.7.12. This will work.

or

2. Try to upgrade Java, spring boot plugins.

Answer (score 0):

The project's `build.gradle` file was wrongly configured, which led to this issue. You should include the `buildscript` block in the `build.gradle` file because the `build.gradle` script itself requires it.

Comment: How to include buildscript block in build.gradle file please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like inconsistency with active Java version and version mentioned in `sourceCompatibility`. Open `External Libraries` in Project window, Java version should be the same (`< 18 >` in your case).